# Method swizzling doesn't work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, method-swizzling

I want to test method swizzling in Objective-C:

1. Add a method `goodName` in `AViewController`

   ```
   #import "AViewController.h"
   #import "UIViewController+Tracking.h"
   @interface AViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation AViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self goodName];
   }
    - (void) goodName {
       NSLog(@"I am a good Name");
   }
   @end
   ```
2. Add a category for swizzling `goodName` method.

   ```
   #import "UIViewController+Tracking.h"
   #import <objc/runtime.h>
   #import "AViewController.h"
   @implementation UIViewController (Tracking)

   + (void) load {
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
       dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
           Class class = [self class];
           SEL originalSelector = @selector(goodName);
           SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(xxx_xxx_goodName);

           Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
           Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

           BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

           if (didAddMethod) {
               class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
           } else {
               method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
           }
       });
   }

   - (void)xxx_xxx_goodName {
       NSLog(@"i am xxx goodName");
       [self xxx_xxx_goodName];
   }

   @end
   ```
3. If everything works well, the `goodName` was called will output `i am xxx goodName`, but it's output `I am a good Name`.

Any part wrong?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? What is the value of `class` (give that var a better name), of `originalMethod`? What does stepping through tell you?

Comment: @CRD Thanks, you give me a hint too, actually it's not ```AViewController```. Thanks!

Comment: The hint was intended :-) Good you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to swizzle methods in AViewController but you put the code in `+(void)load` for base UIViewController. Those are two separate class objects so you need to do it in `+(void)load` for AViewController.